# Using AI to detect damaged parts

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I need to use computer vision to detect damaged parts of cars. I have the images of car before and after damage, how do I use computer vision/ AI to detect that, in this case, left headlight and bumper is damaged. I have a dataset of 70 similar image pairs.
I tried image processing, by overlaying the images on top of each to detect damage. But not all images in the dataset fits when overlaid.
I can Mask RCNN to detect the damaged region but how do I reduce it to the parts being damaged?

Before Damage

[image]

After Damage

[image]

Comment: Okay, what have you tried thus far and what is your question?

Comment: I tried image processing, by overlaying the images on top of each to detect damage. But not all images in the dataset fits when overlaid. A friend told me to use AI, which I don't know how to implement

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Mask R-CNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN). You can train a model with multiple images of damage on cars. Just annotate your data, then train it. Once you have trained, you can then use the splash feature to only highlight areas that you want, i.e, damage. Its fairly easy to set up, and it seems perfect in your case.

Comment: I can use mask Rcnn to localize to the damage but how do I detect the components which are damaged and needs to be replaced?

Comment: @Fazli - You can also do that in Mask R-CNN, just use the splash feature and it will highlight areas of damage for you